# TFRecord format for multiple instances of the same or different classes on one training image

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am trying to train a Faster R-CNN on [grocery dataset](https://github.com/gulvarol/grocerydataset) detection using the new Object Detection API, but I do not quite understand the process of creating a TFRecord file for that. I am aware of the Oxford and VOC dataset examples and the scripts to create TFRecord files, and they work fine if there is only one object in a training image , which is what I see in all of the official examples and github's projects. I have images where more than 20 objects are defined and By the way objects have different classes. I don't want to iterate 20+ times per one image and create 20 almost the same tf_examples where only img_encoded that will be 20+ will take all my space.

```
  tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
      'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
      'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
      'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
      'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
      'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
      'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
      'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
      'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
      'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
      'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
  }))
  return tf_example
```

I believe that the answer for my question in the field that during [creating tf_records](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md)  xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, classes_text, and classes should all be lists with one value per bounding box, so I can add different objects and parameters into these lists per one image.

Maybe someone has experience and can help with advice. The way I've described is going to work or not and if not is there any ways to create tf_recrds for multiple objects in one image in delicate and simple way?

I just put here some features(not all of them) for creating tfrecords the way I think has to work because of what is said in comments(**List of ... (1 per box)**) in link I attached. Hope idea is clean from the attached json.

To clean some situation : xmin for example has 4 different normalized xmins [0.4056372549019608, 0.47794117647058826, 0.4840686274509804, 0.4877450980392157] for 4 different bboxes in attached feature example . Don't forget that lists were converted using **dataset_util.float_list_feature** method into serializable json format. c

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "image/filename"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "C4_P06_N1_S4_1.JPG"
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image/format"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "jpeg"
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image/height"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 2112
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image/key/sha256"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "4e0b458e4537f87d72878af4201c55b0555f10a0e90decbd397fd60476e6e973"
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image/object/bbox/xmax"
    value {
      float_list {
        value: 0.43323863636363635
        value: 0.4403409090909091
        value: 0.46448863636363635
        value: 0.5085227272727273
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image/object/bbox/xmin"
    value {
      float_list {
        value: 0.3565340909090909
        value: 0.36363636363636365
        value: 0.39204545454545453
        value: 0.4318181818181818
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image/object/bbox/ymax"
    value {
      float_list {
        value: 0.9943181818181818
        value: 0.7708333333333334
        value: 0.20265151515151514
        value: 0.9943181818181818
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image/object/bbox/ymin"
    value {
      float_list {
        value: 0.8712121212121212
        value: 0.6174242424242424
        value: 0.06818181818181818
        value: 0.8712121212121212
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "image/object/class/label"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 1
        value: 0
        value: 3
        value: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I kinda did what I thought have to help but I got these numbers during training and that's abnormal.

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 204: loss = 1.4067 (1.177 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 205: loss = 1.0570 (1.684 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 206: loss = 1.0229 (0.916 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 207: loss = 80484784668672.0000 (0.587 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 208: loss = 981436265922560.0000 (0.560 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 209: loss = 303916113723392.0000 (0.539 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 210: loss = 4743170218786816.0000 (0.613 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 211: loss = 2933532187951104.0000 (0.518 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 212: loss = 1.8134 (1.513 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 213: loss = 73507901414572032.0000 (0.553 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 214: loss = 650799901688463360.0000 (0.622 sec/step)
```

**P.S** additional information: for normal view where 1 image has 1 object class from this dataset all works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in that xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, classes_text, and classes are all lists with one value per bounding box.  There is no need to duplicate the image for each bounding box; it would indeed take up a lot of disk space.  As @gautam-mistry pointed out, the records are streamed into tensorflow; as long as each image will fit into RAM you should be okay, even if you duplicated the images (so long as you have the disk space).

Comment: Do you know if `image/object/bbox/truncated` is also a list feature?

Answer (score 0):

TFRecords file represents a sequence of (binary) strings. The format is not random access, so it is suitable for streaming large amounts of data but not suitable if fast sharding or other non-sequential access is desired.

tf.python_io.TFRecordWritertf.python_io.tf_record_iteratortf.python_io.TFRecordCompressionTypetf.python_io.TFRecordOptions

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem --> I had a mistake in my protobuf class file. Different type of classes related to the one number of class. For example:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'raccoon'
}

item {
  id: 1
  name: 'lion'
}
```

And so on, but because I had around 50 classes only in some step loss is went tremendously hight. Maybe it'll help someone, be cautious with proto txt :)